# Inaccessible side-effects in MK

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

In MK (Kelley-Morse) class theory, if i add an axiom that any cardinal except $On$ has an inaccessible greater than it (ie. essentially a Tarski/Grothendiek universe axiom), does that compel me to admit the existence of any other large cardinals (eg. measurable cardinals)?

Broadly what are the known side-effects of an ever increasing sequence of inaccessibles in MK?

For example this answer [Is the axiom of universes 'harmless'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79343/is-the-axiom-of-universes-harmless?rq=1) states that universes are used to resolve Fermats Last Theorem (although they can be dispensed with).

Comment: You cannot deduce any additional large cardinals from this.

Answer (score 3):

This has no noteworthy side-effects that I can think of.  In particular, it does not imply the existence of any stronger kinds of large cardinals.

There's a nice list of large cardinal axioms ordered by their (consistency) strength at [Cantor's attic](http://cantorsattic.info/Upper_attic).  As you can see, the Grothendieck universe axiom is near the very bottom, being the first axiom on the list that is stronger than just the existence of a single inaccessible.  The list is formulated for ZFC rather than MK, but MK only very slightly increases the strength (for instance, MK with a proper class of inaccessibles is still weaker than ZFC with a $1$-inaccessible cardinal in consistency strength).

In concrete terms, pretty much all the stronger kinds of large cardinal are automatically at least $1$-inaccessible (that is, they are inaccessible and are a limit of inaccessible cardinals).  If $\kappa$ is the least $1$-inaccessible cardinal, then $V_{\kappa+1}$ gives a model of MK in which there is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals but no $1$-inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: To the proposer: This also holds in ZFC.  For example if  there exists a measurable cardinal and $k$ is the least measurable cardinal  and $M=(V_k,\epsilon)$ then $M$ satisfies $ ZFC.$ And $\forall x\in M\;( (x\text { is not measurable })^M)$ while $\forall  x\in k\;(x$ is inaccessible $\iff (x$ is inaccessible$)^M).$

Comment: Assuming the consistency of a super-compact cardinal, is it consistent that $k$ is the least super-compact and that $\exists x\in k ((x\text { is super-compact })^{V_k})$ ?